# Performance comparison Sql query and Linq data query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have two opinion about manipulating data with c# programming language environment.

1. (`select * from where ...`) query with sql and get data.
2. (`select * from`) get all data and use Linq query on object list.

What is the performance difference about these opinions for big size or avarage size data. Can I use both of them?

Comment: Loading filtered data is of course better when dealing with big data. But if you have just a few rows and you will frequently change your `where` clouse, then loading all at once can be more reasonable

Comment: Have you considered measuring it?

Comment: The first will be fast 99% of the time. But it's easy to test, so test it? SQL is made to filter large datsets efficently. SQL is not procedural. It works on sets. Sets will filter large datasets almost always faster than a procedural language. LINQ (not LINQ to SQL) will iterate a dataset. So it's basically a wrapper for a foreach loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generic answer to performance is questions is to try it on your data and see which works better.

In your case, though, there is a right answer:  Do the work in the database.

Filtering the data in the database (using the `where`) has two advantages.  First, it reduces the amount of data sent from the database to the application.  This is almost always a win (unless almost all rows are returned).

Second, it allows the database to optimize the query, using (for instance) available indexes to speed the query.

Answer (score 0):

Personally - if you can reduce the amount of data you suck into memory from the database, do it. Why download 10M records, when you needed 100k.. then refine it more with linq for simplicity maybe using local conditions etc.  For small data you can  probably try both - although depending on what your linq is connected to object wise you could still be performing sql anyway, so...

Answer (score -2):

I assume you're talking about **LinqToSql** here and the resulting queries are equivalent. If that is the case the only difference in terms of performance is **LinqToSql** overhead of translating c# expression tree to SQL query. And it's pretty serious as the process involves DB provider which uses reflection and complex logic of converting the tree.

Comment: He says *get all data and use Linq query* so I'd say it's **not** LinqToSQL

Comment: Can you use Linq to get data from plain ADO.NET query?

Comment: Yes. You can use linq on any dataset

Comment: Also the overhead bit assumes that he's loading the data using a different method which isn't clear in the question

Comment: Exactly. That's why I put some assumptions to my answer.

Comment: And about using linq on any dataset. I'd appreciate if you can show me how to use it over `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: Datareader isn't a data set. It's a reader. You'd read the data into a data set (i.e. List<T>) then use linq. It's called [LinqToObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693052.aspx)